# problem connecting to Dockerdb in pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, pgadmin-4

I created a docker file and within it i define my PostgreSQL db
when i run the docker file with docker-compose up it connects to db and i can add records to tables and so on
but when i want to open that db in pgadmin4 it throws this error
[pgadmin4 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqVRw.png) 
any idea where the problem is
p.s : i defined a PGP for my docker image and any time i run docker desktop i should enter the password to connect to

thanks

I search internet but could not find a useful solution